# Trying to get Google coords with PHP .. timing out?

Tags: php, geocoding

I'm trying to get Google lat and long from a user entered address.  I would like to do this before database insertion, but maybe there is a better way?

When I run this function as a standalone, it works and returns coordinates

```
$addressString = "21 Albert St Montreal H2W2H1";
function get_google($addressString){
        if (!is_string($addressString))die("All Addresses must be passed as a string");
        $_url = sprintf('http://maps.google.com/maps?output=js&q=%s',rawurlencode($addressString));
        $_result = false;
        if($_result = file_get_contents($_url)) {
            if(strpos($_result,'errortips') > 1 || strpos($_result,'Did you mean:') !== false) return false;
            preg_match('!center:\s*{lat:\s*(-?\d+\.\d+),lng:\s*(-?\d+\.\d+)}!U', $_result, $_match);
            $_coords['lat'] = $_match[1];
            $_coords['long'] = $_match[2];
        }
        echo $_coords['lat'] . " " . $coords['long']; // echoes correctly
    }
```

.. but when I try this in my code it seems to only return NULL for those values.  (I'm using Codeigniter)

```
$data->name = $this->input->post('name');
$data->address = $this->input->post('address');
$coords = $this->get_google($data->address);
$data->goog_lat = $coords[0];  // seems to be returning NULL
$data->goog_long = $coords[1]; // and i get 'undefined offset' errors (because of NULL, i guess?)
$this->client_model->add_client($data);
```

.. so when I try that I am not getting Google coordinates.. only NULL values.

Can anyone tell me what I am screwing up, or a better way to do this?  Is this because of some timing issue or is it something else?

Comment: You're not returning anything from get_google(), so, what do you expect?

Comment: @MarkBaker  .. sorry.  I had put the echo statement when i demonstrated it as a "standalone" function for testing.  In my code I do use a RETURN statement there.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I was wondering, why not directly use the API? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: @thedjaney Ah.  I was following a php tutorial and it's just how it was presented.  But question: is it normal to geocode before/during a DB insert (with the lag it entails), or is it normal to insert and then get Google co-ords somehow afterwards programmatically?

Comment: you should probably save LatLng only in the database and only get address when needed. #1 it doesn't have to wait for a result. #2, Street names in Google Map may change. If it's really necessary to get the address, you should do it in a separate process so it won't interfere with the main thread. After inserting the LatLng to the table you can then launch a background process to get the address, and even do a periodic update to make sure the addresses are up to date.

Comment: @thedjaney  Thanks for the reply.  I'm actually doing it the other way around.. I'm getting the raw addresses into the database and at some point in the future most (but not all) end up displayed on maps and also processed based on lat/long.  So at some point they need to be geocoded.  I just didn't know if it was typical to geocode before insert, or as a periodic update like you said.  I suppose I will do it as a cronjob ... check for empties and geocode them at non-crucial opportunities. thx.

Answer (score 0):

change the line with echo to

```
return array($_coords['lat'],$coords['long'])
```